# Values are not updated on submit

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to write a simple banking app to learn basic DOM manipulation stuff. This will be a single page website with lots of function calls and hiding/displaying containers.

Once I click the register button on the main screen, it calls registerScreen() function which then hides the main screen elements and shows a form group with text boxes and a submit button that saves the filled in information.

However, it seems that some of my variables take their values from empty text boxes (obviously, those boxes are empty when they are declared) and their values will not update as I type fill them in. So, if i hit the submit button it will pass in empty values.

I added a form validation process and checked local storage to see if it is really passing blank values and it is.

```
function registerScreen() {
    document.getElementById("welcome-container").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("registerScreen").style.display = "block";

    let customerFirstName = document.getElementById('firstName').value;
    let customerLastName = document.getElementById('lastName').value;
    let customerPassword = document.getElementById('password').value;

    let randomID = document.getElementById("randomID");
    let customerId = Math.floor((Math.random() * 999) + 100);


    randomID.innerHTML += customerId;
    document.getElementById("submitInfo").addEventListener("click", () => {saveCustomer(customerId, customerFirstName, customerLastName, customerPassword)});

}

function saveCustomer (customerId, customerFirstName, customerLastName, customerPassword) {
    let customer = {
        id: customerId,
        firstname: customerFirstName,
        lastname: customerLastName,
        password: customerPassword,
        cashAmount: 0,
    }

    if (!validateForm(customerFirstName, customerLastName, customerPassword)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (localStorage.getItem("customers") === null) {
        let customers = [];
        customers.push(customer);
        localStorage.setItem("customers", JSON.stringify(customers));
    } else {
        let customers = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("customers"));
        customers.push(customer);
        localStorage.setItem("customers", JSON.stringify(customers));
    }

    document.getElementById('registerInfo').reset();
    e.preventDefault();

    alert("Registration successful.");
}

function validateForm(customerFirstName, customerLastName, customerPassword) {
    if (!customerFirstName || !customerLastName || !customerPassword) {
        alert('Please fill in the form');
        return false;
    }

    var regularExpression = /^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{6,16}$/;
    var regex = new RegExp(expression);

    if (!customerPassword.match(regex)) {
        alert('Please use a valid password');
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

How can I pass the updated version of these elements?

Comment: Where does `e` come from in saveCustomer, you need to transfer it from your addEventListener implementation to the saveCustomer method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prevent the default handling of the event, then you need to transfer it from your addEventListener call to your saveCustomer function.

As your code is now, you wont prevent the form from being submitted (i suspect your submitInfo input element is of type "submit")

One solution could be to modify these two lines in your code:

```
    ....
    document.getElementById("submitInfo").addEventListener("click", () => {saveCustomer(customerId, customerFirstName, customerLastName, customerPassword)});
}

function saveCustomer (customerId, customerFirstName, customerLastName, 
     customerPassword) {
```

to

```
    ....
    document.getElementById("submitInfo").addEventListener("click", (e) => {saveCustomer(e,customerId, customerFirstName, customerLastName, customerPassword)});
    }

function saveCustomer (e,customerId, customerFirstName, customerLastName, customerPassword) {
```

Second, you initialize your variables in the registerScreen method, this means that the values send to saveCustomer() will not reflect any changes made in your form, you could fix this by moving

```
 let customerFirstName = document.getElementById('firstName').value;
 let customerLastName = document.getElementById('lastName').value;
 let customerPassword = document.getElementById('password').value;

 let randomID = document.getElementById("randomID");
 let customerId = Math.floor((Math.random() * 999) + 100);
```

to the beginning of the saveCustomer() function, and then you no longer need to pass them as variables to the saveCustomer() function

Comment: Yes, it has a "submit" type. I tried this but it still will not work, unfortunately.

Comment: You also need to fetch the values from your form, i will update the answer in a sec